# "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).placeholder is not a function" при установке анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("input").click(function(){ 
         $('input, textarea').placeholder().animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Вы используете какой-то плагин $.placeholder? Или вы полагаете, что в jQuery есть такая функция по умолчанию?

Comment: Я искал по интернету jquery placeholder animate и я только это нашел.

Comment: Значит вы явно что-то упустили там, где это нашли.

Comment: @Murad Приведите список подключаемых библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобное можно сделать с помощью label и CSS.

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
input {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}
input + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 55px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
}
input:focus + label {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="validate">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите таким странным способом анимировать плейсхолдер, то так сделать нельзя(!). Можно лишь имитировать сдвиг плейсхолдера. В этом вопросе вам поможет например этот плагин: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/label_better_demo.html